# friendly url in codeigniter with variables in url

Tags: codeigniter, friendly-url

I'm making a site using Codeigniter and my URL for a particular product page is like http://www.domain.com/products/display/$category_id/$product_id/$offset

$offset is used for limiting the number of pages shown per page when using the Codeigniter's Pagination library.

How I want to make it such that my URL is something more human friendly, like http://www.domain.com/$category_name/$product_name/$offset ie. http://www.domain.com/weapons/proton-canon/3

Can anyone point me the general approach? I just started learning codeigniter and is working on my first project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use what's generally known as a URL slug to achieve this.

Add a new field to your table, called "url_slug" or similar. Now you will need to create a slug for each product, and store it in this field.

CI has a function in the URL helper - `url_title($string)` which will take a string, and convert it for use in URL's.

For example `My product name` would become `my_product_name`.

Now, in your method, you can either - keep the `product_id` intact, use this as a parameter for your method to show specific products, and use the slug for human friendly links, or you can just use the `url_slug` to refer to products.

Your URL may look like:

`www.domain.com/$category_name/$product_id/my_cool_product/$offset`

or it could look like

`www.domain.com/$category_name/my_cool_product/$offset`

with no ID. the choice is yours, but the url_slug may change - the ID won't. Which may have SEO impacts.

Regardless, your method needs to look something like:

```
function display_product($product_id, $url_slug, $offset) {
   // do what you gotta do...
}
```

You can then use URL's like the above.

You will need to use URI routing as well, as the example above will attempt to look for a controller called `$category_name` and a method called `my_cool_product`, which will of course not exist.

See [URI Routing for further info](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).